# SetonClickListerner is not working if I add Views to LinerLayout Programmatically using For Loop in Android

Tags: android, android-view

**What I am doing:**

I am adding TextView and Imageview  to LinearLayout Programmatically using For Loop[code is added below]

**What Output and Issue I am Getting :**

[image]

**What I want :**
    I want to implement "setOnClickListener" for all imageviews

**Problem I am Getting :** 
    If I Click on last imageview[5th one],setOnClickListener is working,But For Remaining it is not working,Could anyone help me to rectify this problem?

**Codind and XML :**

**Xml  : Layout Name is : car**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/string_mmed"
        android:textColor="#444"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carType"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/mmed_type"
        android:textColor="#444"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
      <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/carImageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:src="@drawable/info" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Coding  : //Declartion**

```
TextView carName,carType;
ImageView carImageView
LinearLayout carLinearLayout;

oncreate(){
    carLinearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.carLinearLayout);
}
```

**//To Iterate and displayview 5 times**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            View child = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.car, null);
            getCarViews(child);
            carName.setText("geting from getter setter");
            carType.setText("geting from getter setter");
            carLinearLayout.addView(child);
}
 carImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**//Intialization**

```
getCarViews(View child){
carName= (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.carName);
carType= (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.carType);
carImageView= (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.carImageView);
}
```

Comment: Where you have set the click listener for your imageview?

Comment: are you adding clicklistener for new added view?

Comment: @Pr38y,yes..see my edited code

Comment: @GrIsHu,As of now I added that after forloop,But I dont know whether that is correct or not..Correct me if it is wrong

Comment: add listener to the `child` view inside for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it shows that you have added click listener outside your loop so it will always set click listener for the lastly added view only as the for loop gets executed. You will have to add click listener inside your for loop to get all the `ImageView's` click event.

Try to set the click listener for your `ImageView` as your inflate it 5 times as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    View child = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.car, null);
    getCarViews(child);
    carName.setText("geting from getter setter");
    carType.setText("geting from getter setter");
    carImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    carLinearLayout.addView(child);
}
```

Comment: OK,Let me try this.and Let you know the status

Comment: I tried ,It is saying "you can accept an answer in 5 minutes"..I will do after 5 minutes :-)